# replace random words in a string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I want to create a function that replaces random words in a string. Here is what I thought of.

1. Given a string I would give a random index position within that string.
2. From that index I will replace the nearest word with a word that I want
3. Along with that I would store the word I just replace into some storage variable/database/file

Ex.

Random word seed: tree, cat, wolf, apple

String: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Possible Results:

1. The apple brown fox jumps cat the lazy dog.
2. The quick brown wolf tree over the lazy dog.
3. The quick tree fox tree over the lazy apple.

Comment: get length of string -> get random integer within that range -> get character at that index, if whitespace increment index till you find a word. -- best would be to use regular expressions i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest code would be had by

1. Splitting the string into an array words (e.g. with `explode` or `preg_split` for more heavy-duty logic)
2. Replacing randomly selected entries in the array as you see fit
3. Joining the words back into a string with (e.g. `implode`)

Answer (score 2):

Simply `explode` the string on spaces, and use a `rand()` to replace. Like:

```
<?php
$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
$aWords = explode($string, " ");
foreach ($aWords as $word)
{
    if(rand(1,2) == 1)
    {
        //replace the word
    }
}
// implode the string
?>
```

Comment: You used wrong syntax `$aWords = explode($string, " ");`

Right one is: `$aWords = explode(" ",$string);`