# Select & replace a random word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write a code in javascript that selects a random word from a text, and replaces it for another word.

Here's my code:

```
var text = "dog cat apple stone";
var keyword = text[Math.floor(Math.random()*text.length)]; // select random word
var new_phrase = text.replace( keyword, "house"); // replace for other word

document.write("<p>" + text + "</p>" );
document.write("<p>" + new_phrase + "</p>");
```

However, this replaces a letter in the text not a word. Like this: "dog chouset apple stone"

How can I select a random word not a letter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447943/replace-random-words-in-a-string

Comment: you are not selecting a word, you are getting a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `text[someIndex]` you are selecting one character from `text`. Try splitting the string and use the resulting array:

```
var text = "dog cat apple stone"
   ,txttmp = text.split(/\s+/)
   ,keyword = txttmp[Math.floor(Math.random()*txttmp.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to Kepp it Simple principle i would say

```
var text = "dog cat apple stone";
arrText = text.split(" ");
```

it will give you and array of words back. After replacing any word in array you can again use

```
arrText.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

you can store the values and then refer back to them with an index and get the value back.

```
var text=["dog","cat","apple", "stone"];

var keyword = Math.floor((Math.random()*text.length)); 
text[keyword] = "house"; // replace for other word

document.write("<p>" + text + "</p>" );
```